# Proper Passenger + Apache Permissions to fix error "No such file or directory - config/environment.rb"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-2.2, phusion-passenger

I am having a problem with Passenger not being able to start due to an apparently common issue in which Passenger claims: No such file or directory - config/environment.rb.

I have searched the web high and low and this appears to be a permissions related issue. It is my understanding that Passenger runs as the owner of config.ru and config/environment.rb file. In my case this owner is "admin". I am running the app root in the home directory of the admin user. So I believe I have the correct permissions set using:
`sudo chown -R admin:admin /home/admin/www`
and
`sudo chmod -R 755 /home/admin/www`

where the app root is located at:
/home/admin/www/app

Here is my virtual server config file:

> ```
>  <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerName track.example.com
>     DocumentRoot /home/admin/www/app/current/public
>     <Directory /home/admin/www/app/current/public>
>     Options FollowSymLinks
>     AllowOverride none
>     Order allow,deny
>     Allow from all
>     </Directory>
>     PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
>     RailsBaseURI /
>     PassengerAppRoot /home/admin/www/app
>     RailsEnv production   
>     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
>     # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
>     # alert, emerg.
>     LogLevel debug
>     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

I am running Ubuntu 12.0.4, Rails 3.2.8, Ruby 1.9.3, Passenger 3.0.18, Apache 2

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I have issues I don't understand I usually reboot a fresh drive on my linode and quickly do a bare-minimum install to see if my list of steps work. Sometimes my other actions in the server would cause problems so it's important that the bare-minimum install works before I look at other factors.

As for Passenger you can't rely on its generated error messages 100%. Sometimes you could be missing an index.html file or a view file but if you read Passenger's error it's like you messed up ten different things.

I recently got Passenger to work from scratch so here's list of what I did:

- Did not touch anything with regards to permission (other than what you've done_I just did the CHOWN step; no CHMOD step).
- Did not have to touch config.ru or config/environments.rb
- Cleared tmp using `rm -rf /tmp/*`
- I installed from gemfile (not tarball); ran the `gem install passenger` cmd (with a 2GB swap).
- Ran the `passenger-install-apache2-module` cmd. Passenger will give 5 lines of code to paste into httpd.conf at the end. Did that.

Virtualhost config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/app/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart apache and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Passenger is a module for Apache, running as part of the Apache process. This means the Apache user needs to have the permissions to the project. From the [Passenger documentation for Apache](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_to_a_virtual_host_8217_s_root_2):

> You may also need to tweak your file/folder permissions. Make sure
>   that the following folders are readable and executable by Apache:
>
> ```
> * this public folder.
>
> * the application’s config folder.
>
> * all parent folders. That is, /webapps/rackapp and /webapps must also be readable and executable by Apache.
> ```

Comment: OK. I modified my permissions and granted the www-data group read & execute permissions on all folders and files from /home/ on down just to open things up for troubleshooting. I am still getting the same Passenger message. Passenger-status shows that Passenger is indeed running and mysql is up and running too. I have touched the /tmp/restart.txt file as well as restarted Apache to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PassengerAppRoot` is wrong. You specified `/home/admin/www/app` but your app is actually in `/home/admin/www/app/current`. This is why Passenger can't find it.

The resolution is to fix the configuration.

```
    PassengerAppRoot /home/admin/www/app/current
```