# Passenger complains about Apache permissions despite 777

Tags: permissions, apache-2.4, phusion-passenger, redmine

I installed Redmine on Fedora 18. The installation works when tested with webrick, as explained in the [official HowTo](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall).

Now I want to use Passenger and Apache to host Redmine. What I get is:

> Passenger error #2
>   An error occurred while trying to access '/var/www/redmine/config/environment.rb': Cannot stat '/var/www/redmine/config/environment.rb': Permission denied (errno=13)
>
> Apache doesn't have read permissions to that file. Please fix the relevant file permissions.

After several unsuccessful tries to resolve the problem, I gave the ownership of the whole `/var/www/redmine` directory including contents to the apache user *and* changed the permissions recursively to 777. I su'd to the apache user and could open and stat the environment.rb file without any problem. So I think that it is not a permission problem after all, but faced with this explicit error message, I am out of ideas.

What could be the problem here, and any ideas how to fix it (preferably a solution which allows me to change the permissions back to a sensible value)?

*footnotes*:

- This is possibly related to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/449371/proper-passenger-apache-permissions-to-fix-error-no-such-file-or-directory).
- I didn't forget to restart apache after changing the permissions.
- I am running httpd version 2.4.4-2.fc18, Phusion Passenger version 4.0.4 Redmine version 2.3.1.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/364677/why-is-chmod-r-777-destructive). This is probably related to SELinux, what AVC denials have you logged so far?

Comment: @dawud thank you, I had not thought that Fedora may have SELinux enabled by default. As for the link, maybe I was not clear enough - I did not set full permissions to the whole system, just to a subfolder of /var/www, on a system which is not yet in production use. If you want to add an answer, I will accept yours.

Comment: Check my comment on your answer. Try the solution i proposed there, and if you can make it work, edit your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten that Fedora has SELinux enabled by default. Turning off SELinux removed the error.

As pointed out by dawud, turning off SELinux should not be considered a solution - rather, SELinux should be configured to permit Apache to use the files.

The quick solution was to run `restorecon` on the directory in question. This sets the security context to the type expected of the parent directory. My files being in a subdirectory of /var/www, they were set to httpd_sys_content_t, and Apache was allowed to access them. If they had been somewhere else, I would have had to change the type manually.

After solving the SELinux issue, the file permissions can be chmoded back to the usual level without further problems.

Comment: [Don't disable SELinux](http://stopdisablingselinux.com/), please. If you are not versed enough in it so as to set it up properly, at least set a [permissive domain](http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/42394.html) for Apache instead of disabling it.

Comment: @dawud While security is not a problem in my very limited case (this is a personal project and the machine is only accessible from the local network), good point about getting a robust solution for the general case. At least it was a good diagnosis for the root cause.

Comment: @dawud answer expanded to include the proper solution.